# set rule custom JSR223 Assertion and validate response using Jmeter

Tags: javascript, jmeter

hello there can somebody help me, I am validating the response of an api, I need to validate that
at least one of the 3 tests is true, this api performs 3 requests

```
  var dataStr = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
  var data = JSON.parse(dataStr);

  if(data.IsSuccessful == true) {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(false);
  } 
  else {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true);
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('fail');
  }

  ResponseApi Post

  {
   "IsSuccessful":false,
   "IsError":true,
   "ErrorMessage":"Error"
  }
```

IsSuccessful indicates if the response was successful
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyI7i.png

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have `JSON.parse()` function in JMeter even if you choose `javascript` as the language, switch to `groovy` and replace first lines of your assertion code to:

```
def data = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())
```

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)

if you need more assistance (your "validate that at least one of the 3 tests is true" statement is not clear) - consider updating your question with full response data from the API and indicate your custom pass/fail criteria